# Remove substring from string between special characters in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I was looking for an answer but I failed. My question is a bit peculiar and I'm still learing regex. I'd like to achieve, from this:

```
str1 <- 'txt1/txt2/123|abc_def_123|1991-02-11'
```

something like this:

```
txt1|abc_def_123|1991-02-11
```

so everything from `/` (included) to first occurence of `|` should be removed.
So far I wrote this one:

```
sub("\\/.*\\|", "|", str1 )
```

but it removes everything to the last occurence of `|`

```
"txt1|1991-02-11"
```

How can I point out that the substring should be removed to he first occurence of `|`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following your attempt, you can make your regex lazy

```
sub("/.*?\\|", "|", str1 )
#[1] "txt1|abc_def_123|1991-02-11"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/[^|]*` which takes the first `/` and everything after this as long as it is not a `|`.

```
sub("/[^|]*", "", str1)
#[1] "txt1|abc_def_123|1991-02-11"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a negated character class with a positive lookahead

```
/[^|]*(?=\|)
```

To not cross newlines, you could extend the negated character class:

```
/[^|\r\n]*(?=\|)
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9zsskx/1)

```
str1 <- 'txt1/txt2/123|abc_def_123|1991-02-11'
sub("/[^|]*(?=\\|)", "", str1, perl=TRUE)
```

Output

```
[1] "txt1|abc_def_123|1991-02-11"
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is by using backreference:

```
sub("(^.*)/.*/.*?(\\|.*$)", "\\1\\2", str1)
[1] "txt1|abc_def_123|1991-02-11"
```

Here, the double backreference `\\1\\2` 'recalls' the strings in the two capturing groups `(...)`, while the parts not included in capturing groups get removed.